# Can I use my local C drive as a server

Tags: postgresql

I just downloaded postgresql and I want to add a server in pgAdmin.  For learning purposes, how can I connect to a test database, or create one on my local C drive and use that as a server?  Or is this possible?

Comment: It's funny to me how I get the downvotes due to 'this question does not show any research' when in fact I did alot of research and couldn't find anything.  And by anything I mean something that someone totally  new to this would understand.  If I had found this question with the answers below it would have indeed helped me in my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run PostgreSQL locally on your C drive. Just install PostgreSQL and in the pgAdmin there should be a 'search for DB instance' function. Use that and your local install should show up.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere..most of the tools aren't available

Comment: Make sure you install Postgre sql and then make sure the DB instance is running.

Comment: When I downloaded, it came with Application stack builder, pgadminIII, reload config and SQL shell.

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem exactly? Is this on Windows?

Comment: This is on windows.  How do I create a database on my c drive and view it in pgadmin?

Comment: Okay, then connect to your instance: (your going to use localhost for the Host field) http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/connect.html - Let me know if you get that far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26739/discussion-between-kfp-and-jordan)

Answer (score 0):

if it is for test purposes that would be fine, but just make sure the server isn't visible on the network (set some passwords) especially if you use public wifi!